# PHP Upload/Download size limit for files

Tags: php, memory, download, upload

I would like to understand if this application is suitable for Apache/PHP.
I want to do something like WeTransfer service where I upload a big file to this web application and it makes a public web link to download the file.

I have some doubt about the streaming/buffering capabilities of Apache/PHP web server. 
Can you confirm that if I want to upload or download a file of 2GB with a PHP script I need to set at least the same memory_limit because POST data is not buffered?

Comment: That is not how streaming works. Of course the http server does _not_ load all files fully into memory! To streams the data which means it only loads parts of the file and delivers those, acting in an iterative manner. So you do not have to raise the memory limit for the php process, if you implement the streaming in a sane way.

Comment: Ok but when my PHP script starts post data is already fully received, am I wrong? I think this is the real difference between other webserver when I can manage request object.

Comment: So you are talkihng about the uploading process. It depends on how the upload is implemented. If it is a file upload then no, the data is not kept im memory but in a temporary file which is offered to the processing php script. If the file is sent as post body itself then yes, there is no way around keeping it in memory, but that is true for all http servers.

Comment: Exists an HTTP method to send a file without body post? As far as I know this is the only way with php.

Comment: There always is a body in a POST request, although it might indeed be empty. There are conventions however that allow the http server to treat parts of the body different. What is typically done is a "multi part" upload which declares one or more parts of the upload as "files" which allows the http server to store those parts into temporary files instead of holding everything in memory.